# Determine if PDOStatement object originated from PDO::query() or PDO::prepare()

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

Both `PDO::query()` and `PDO::prepare()` return a PDOStatement object but the two are used differently:

- A PDOStatement from `PDO::query()` is ready for immediate use with `fetch()` or `fetchAll()`
- A PDOSatement from `PDO::prepare()` needs to be populated with `bind()` run with `execute()` before you can use `fetch()`

Is there a way I can differentiate between a PDOSatement that came from `PDO::query()` versus one that came from `PDO::prepare()`?

Comment: Why would you need to?

Comment: Because I want to ;) That said... I've been playing around with some pdo wrapper that can handle many stmt objects. And it become necessary to tell them apart.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that you *can* tell them apart.  Both `PDO::prepare()` `PDO::query()` return a [`PDOStatement`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) object which doesn't appear to have any methods for determining its origin.

That being said, the [`debugDumpParams()`](https://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php) function does include a parameter count in the output, but you'd need to manually capture and parse the output text to obtain it.

Comment: I thought that I missed something obvious. It's ok if it's not possible. I can mark it in some other way. Thanks.